# keras / tensorflow requires unnecessary values fed to placeholders

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, keras

I'm using Keras with TF backend. Recently, when using the functional API to make "hybrid" models, it seemed to me that Keras requires me to feed values that it shouldn't need.

As a background, I am trying to implement a conditional GAN in Keras. My implementation has a generator and a discriminator. As an example, the generator accepts (20, 20, 1) inputs and returns (20, 20, 1) outputs. These are stacked by channel to produce a (20, 20, 2) input to the discriminator. The discriminator is supposed to decide whether it is seeing a ground-truth translation of the original (20, 20, 1) image or a translation by the generator. This is represented by 0=fake, 1=real.

By itself, the discriminator is just a CNN for binary classification. Therefore, it can be trained by feeding data points with inputs of shape (20, 20, 2) and outputs in {0,1}. Therefore, if I write something like:

```
# <disc> is the discriminator
arbitrary_input = np.full(shape=(5, 20, 20, 2), fill_value=0.5)
arbitrary_labels = np.array([1, 1, 0, 0, 1])
disc.fit(arbitrary_input, arbitrary_labels, epochs=5)
```

training will proceed without errors (obviously this is a useless dataset, though).

However, when I insert the discriminator into the generator-discriminator stack:

```
# <disc> is the discriminator, <gen> is the generator
input = Input(shape=(20, 20, 1), name='stack_input')
gen_output = gen(input)
pair = Concatenate(axis=FEATURES_AXIS)([input, gen_output])
disc_output = disc(gen_output)

stack = Model(input, disc_output)
stack.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy')

arbitrary_input = np.full(shape=(5, 20, 20, 2), fill_value=0.5)
arbitrary_labels = np.array([1, 1, 0, 0, 1])

disc.fit(arbitrary_input, arbitrary_labels, epochs=5)
```

suddenly I need to feed an extra placeholder. I get this error message on disc.fit():

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'stack_input' with dtype float
     [[Node: stack_input = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

As you can see by the name, this is the input to the hybrid/stacked model. I haven't changed the discriminator at all, I have only included it in another model. Therefore disc.fit() should still work, right?

There's a workaround available by freezing the weights of the generator and using fit() on the full stack, I think, but I do not understand why the method above doesn't work.

Is it perhaps some issue with scoping?

Edit: The discriminator is really just a simple CNN. It is initialized with `disc = pix2pix_discriminator(input_shape=(20, 20, 2), n_filters=(32, 64))`. The function in question is:

```
def pix2pix_discriminator(input_shape, n_filters, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding='same', alpha=0.2):
x = Input(shape=input_shape, name='disc_input')

    # first layer
    h = Conv2D(filters=n_filters[0],
               kernel_size=kernel_size,
               strides=strides,
               padding=padding,
               data_format=DATA_FORMAT)(x)
    # no BatchNorm
    h = LeakyReLU(alpha=alpha)(h)

    for i in range(1, len(n_filters)):
        h = Conv2D(filters=n_filters[i],
                   kernel_size=kernel_size,
                   strides=strides,
                   padding=padding,
                   data_format=DATA_FORMAT)(h)
        h = BatchNorm(axis=FEATURES_AXIS)(h)
        h = LeakyReLU(alpha=alpha)(h)

    h_flatten = Flatten()(h)  # required for the upcoming Dense layer
    y_pred = Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid')(h_flatten)  # binary output

    discriminator = Model(inputs=x, outputs=y_pred)
    discriminator.compile(optimizer='adam',
                          loss='binary_crossentropy',
                          metrics=['accuracy'])
    return discriminator
```

Comment: Could add the line of the code that initializes/defines disc? Could you clarify if you intend to feed the model real data? If so, what is the intended entry point for the data? I see you feed arbitrary_input with a tensor of constant values 0.5. Is this intended? Should it be real data?

Comment: I've edited the question to include the discriminator's architecture, although I  am pretty sure it's just a CNN. I will of course feed real data later, but the pipeline should work for fake data just as well as real data, so I'm testing with that for now.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `disc_output = disc(pair)`?